#  What is the affect of CONVERT() on INDEX while searching?

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, indexing

I am using SQL Server 2008. I have a Non-Unique Non-clustered index on a DateTime Column "DateFrom". I am searching the table based on this column. I just wanted to know the affect of **CONVERT() function** on INDEX see below:

```
Query1:
SELECT  *
FROM    myTable
WHERE   CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DateFrom,23) >= '2011-01-01'

Query2:
SELECT  *
FROM    myTable
WHERE   DateFrom >= '2011-01-01 00:00:00.000'
```

I have checked & found no difference. But i was thinking that since the column is CONVERTED, so the index may not be used by the SQL Server, is it correct?

**Please forgive me, if this is not a proper question.**

Comment: o.DateFrom - there is no alias to o - slight typo?

Comment: *I have checked & found no difference* - are you saying you actually compared execution plans and found them identical? I doubt that; the first query compares strings using rules for strings, the second compares dates.

Comment: If you are on 2008 and casting `datetime` to `date` it can still use an index but this is very much the exception to the rule.

Comment: @GSerg, Thanks
Not the execution plans, i just compared the time taken by both the SQLs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Generally, when you have a function on the left side of the comparison in a WHERE clause, the server will be unable to utilize the index on the referenced column.

In your first example, there is no comparison to the DateFrom column directly. Instead, you are using a function on the column. When the server expands this, it must perform the function on each column value, and the resulting value is not indexed. Therefore, no index can be used to improve the query.

Also, in your first example, you indicated that the DateFrom column is a datetime column. Yet, you're converting the column to a string and doing a string comparison. Hence, the server will not use your datetime index.

In your second example, you are comparing the constant value with the date column directly, so the server may utilize the index. The server will convert the string constant on the right side of the comparison into a datetime value. However, it won't use the index in all cases. For example, if you have a very few number of rows, the server may decide not to use the index and just scan the few rows.

Both queries may yield the same result set, but they are still very different.

Comment: Thanks, let me try it on large data.

Comment: Is this the case with converting an integer-type column to a string-type column? Looking at an EF query that's doing `.Where(x => x.Id.ToString().Equals(searchTerm))` and wondering if that'd use the index.