# Output data from current month?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this table and i want to ge the data from current month.
This is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CSEReduxResponses](
        [response_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [submitterdept] [int] NOT NULL,
        [commentdate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
        [status] [int] NOT NULL,
        [approvedby] [int] NULL,
        [approveddate] [datetime] NULL,
            [execoffice_approvedby] [int] NULL,

     CONSTRAINT [PK_CSE_Responses] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
```

I want to get the data where
status=1 and execoffice_status=0 and the current date.I want to use the approveddata column to get the date.
Right now I have

```
select * from CSEReduxResponses WHERE STATUS=1 AND EXECOFFICE_STATUS=0;
```

I have Microsoft sql server 2008

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio   10.0.2531.0

Answer (score 2):

Add `AND MONTH([approveddate]) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND YEAR([approveddate]) = YEAR(GETDATE())` to your where clause, assuming `[approveddate]` is the date you're interested in.

Comment: If the columns are indexed, keep in mind using functions on it [may prevent the database from utilizing indexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122821/what-is-the-affect-of-convert-on-index-while-searching/8123017#8123017). A more index-friendly option is use a date range ie `WHERE ApprovedDate >= @firstOfThisMonth AND ApprovedDate < @firstOfNextMonth`

Answer (score 1):

It is simple:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   CSEReduxResponses 
WHERE  STATUS = 1 
AND    EXECOFFICE_STATUS = 0;
AND    MONTH(commentdate) = MONTH(GETDATE())
AND    YEAR(commentdate) = YEAR(GETDATE())
```