# Invalid column name error on query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM CSEReduxDepts, CSEReduxResponses
        WHERE CSEReduxDepts.csedept_id = CSEReduxResponses.employeedept
            AND CSEReduxResponses.status = 1
            AND CSEReduxResponses.execoffice_status = 1
            AND MONTH([CSEReduxResponses.approveddate]) = MONTH(GETDATE())
        ORDER BY approveddate
```

If I take out the `AND MONTH([CSEReduxResponses.approveddate]) = MONTH(GETDATE())`
it will work, but I want to get the data only from this month. How can I get it to work?

Comment: I guess there's no `approveddate` column in the `CEReduxResponses` table. Check your spelling.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: What is you take out the square brackets?  What database server are you using?

Comment: I think, you should remove the square brackets.

Comment: Why are you 1) using square brackets, 2) naming the column prefixing it with its table name in the AND statement, and not in the ORDER BY clause? Plus I agree with @marc_s, you should really reconsider using this old-style join.

Comment: @guneli , thanks that is actually what you do

Comment: @will yes i agree i will look into changing them all into the "new" style

Comment: *get the data only from this month* The query above will not do that. You need to filter on year or the results will include data from other years as well. See your other thread [for a more index-friendly way of filtering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23090210/output-data-from-current-month#comment35301869_23090293)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brackets indicate a scope like a table or column.  By putting brackets around both, you are telling sql server that its one element.

This would work:

```
[CSEReduxResponses].[approveddate]
```

But you should probably just remove them.

Also, as noted in the comments, using SQL92 syntax would be better here.

```
SELECT * 
FROM CSEReduxDepts d
inner join CSEReduxResponses r on d.csedept_id = r.employeedept
                              and r.status = 1
                              and r.execoffice_status = 1
Where
     MONTH(r.approveddate) = MONTH(GETDATE())
ORDER BY approveddate
```

Comment: it seems ,The multi-part identifier "CSEReduxResponses.approveddate" could not be bound.

Comment: This might be because TSQL cannot figure out which `approveddate` column to use if you have two, one `approveddate` column for each table. Otherwise, this might as well mean that there is no `approveddate` column in the `CSEReduxResponses` table.

Comment: @user3408399, try it now.  I had failed to use the alias in the where clause.  Silly copy paste error.  My appologies

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select *
    from CSEReduxDepts d
        inner join CSEReduxResponses r on r.employeedept = d.csdept
    where r.status = 1
        and r.execoffice_status = 1
        and MONTH(r.approveddate) = MONTH(GETDATE())
    order by r.approveddate asc
```

The use of square brackets within a TSQL query/statement is only to allow the use of reserved words, or other special characters like so:

```
select r.[Approved Date]
```

You may see that the column name uses a space, so that is an appropriate use of the square brackets. Or else, just like in French:

```
select r.[Date Approuvé]
```

Which would indeed not be accepted outside of square brackets.

Here's an example with a keyword:

```
select r.[month]
```

Which tells TSQL to interpret the word `month` as a column name, and not like the TSQL `MONTH()` function.