# Comparing with date or datetime columns in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

We are migrating from Oracle to SQL Server (using SSMA). In our Oracle environment, we were using the `DATE` datatype for some columns, during the datatype mapping for SQL Server we set `DATETIME` datatype for the corresponding columns.

Now, suppose I have a table as follows:

```
+--------+-------------+---------------------------+
| grn_id | grn_no      | grn_dt                    |
+--------+-------------+---------------------------+
| 1      | 0000000001  | 2018-01-03 00:00:00.000   |
| 2      | 0000000002  | 2018-01-03 00:00:00.000   |
| 3      | 0000000003  | 2018-01-03 00:00:00.000   |
| 4      | 0000000001  | 2018-01-27 00:00:00.000   |
+--------+-------------+---------------------------+
```

I'm trying to filter this data with `grn_dt(DATATYPE IS DATETIME)` with a string like `'2018-01-27'`. What is the right way to do this?

We have already used a convert function as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM grn_header WHERE convert(date,grn_dt) <= '2018-01-27'
```

Anyway, we are getting the required output, but is this conversion right?

Do I have to set the conversion for the string (`'2018-01-27'`) also as follows?

```
SELECT * FROM grn_header WHERE convert(date,grn_dt) <= convert(date,'2018-01-27')
```

Is there any alternative way to do this?

Comment: *Don't* use strings in the first place, use parameterized queries with date parameters. If you can't (why?) use the unseparated date format, `YYYYMMDD`. The format you used can be affected by the `DATEFORMAT` environment setting

Comment: If you want to store dates only, use the `date` type in SQL Server instead of `datetime`. If you want to store the time component too, use `datetime2` with the precision you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fine:

```
where convert(date, grn_dt) <= '2018-01-27'
```

SQL Server will use an index, if available, on `grn_dt` despite the `convert()`.

I am also inclined to write this as:

```
where grn_dt < dateadd(day, 1, '2018-01-27')
```

Comment: `YYYY-MM-DD` is affected by DATEFORMAT. The string literal should be YYYYMMDD at least.

Comment: You sure about the convert function index [usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122821/what-is-the-affect-of-convert-on-index-while-searching)? unless the (modern) SQL Server optimizers are smart enough to see it can rewrite and handle `convert(date, grn_dt) <= '2018-01-27'` as `grn_dt <= 2018-01-26 23:59:59` (assuming `grn_dt` column is a `DATETIME` datatype)

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes, going back *at least* to 2008R2. Probably earlier. The mechanism is called dynamic seek. [Check this DBA question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea). Just check the execution plan.

Comment: @RaymondNijland the second answser in that question shows that newer SQL Server versions fixed the cardinality issues that SQL Server 2008 R2 had

Comment: looks interesting @PanagiotisKanavos o its a decade old feature already..

Comment: @RaymondNijland : Yeah it is a DATETIME column and Thankyou for your comment