# Postgresql - index strategy for a date field in a jsonb column

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Is there any best practice for dealing with date fields in jsonb columns?
In the following scenario, I am trying to find 'Patients' based on their birth date.

```
SELECT P.resource ->> 'id' ID, P.resource -> 'birthDate' DoB, CONCAT(P.resource -> 'name' -> 0 -> 'given', ' ', P.resource -> 'name' -> 0 -> 'family') "name"
FROM recorditems P
WHERE  P.resource ->> 'resourceType' = 'Patient'
    AND (P.resource ->> 'birthDate')::date BETWEEN '1975-01-01'::date AND '1995-01-01'::date;
```

A gin index might come handy for the first predicate if I rewrite it using the `@>` operator. Is there any index suggestion for the second predicate? Wont the string-to-date conversion be a performance overhead?

`explain analyze` says the following:

```
 Gather  (cost=1000.00..229569.96 rows=39 width=96) (actual time=6.178..1205.812 rows=699 loops=1)
   Workers Planned: 2
   Workers Launched: 2
   ->  Parallel Seq Scan on recorditems p  (cost=0.00..228566.06 rows=16 width=96) (actual time=13.747..1172.495 rows=233 loops=3)
         Filter: (((resource ->> 'resourceType'::text) = 'Patient'::text) AND (((resource ->> 'birthDate'::text))::date >= '1975-01-01'::date)
AND (((resource ->> 'birthDate'::text))::date <= '1995-01-01'::date))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 524492
 Planning Time: 0.068 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 12
   Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 2.296 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 0.891 ms, Emission 16.132 ms, Total 19.320 ms
 Execution Time: 1206.889 ms
(12 rows)

Time: 1207.337 ms (00:01.207)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The perfect index for that query would be:

```
CREATE INDEX ON recorditems (
   (resource ->> 'resourceType'),
   ((resource ->> 'birthDate')::date)
);
```

That does not work, because the cast from `text` to `date` is not `IMMUTABLE` (try `SELECT 'today'::date;`).

If you know there are only ISO dates stored, you could work around that with a custom function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION text_to_date(text) RETURNS date
   IMMUTABLE LANGUAGE sql AS
'SELECT CAST($1 AS date)';
```

Then you have to use that function in your query and index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON recorditems (
   (resource ->> 'resourceType'),
   (text_to_date(resource ->> 'birthDate'))
);
```

Comment: What about the type conversion? Wouldn't that be a problem at all - in terms of index usage and execution overhead?

Comment: @MaheshVS index is created after converting birthDate to date data type

Comment: @ArjunVachhani - I was referring to the conversion in the query. Based on my experience with MSSQL, when you apply conversion on a field, index will not be used - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122821/what-is-the-affect-of-convert-on-index-while-searching I would like to know if that is the case for Postgres as well.

Comment: If you use a type cast in your query, then you also have to use a type cast in your index definition, as I did in my answer. Did you try it?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I am unable to create the index - It says ERROR:  functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE

Comment: Oh, I didn't think of that. I have suggested a workaround in my updated answer.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I have updated the new query plan into the question for your reference. It seems the query plan is not using the date field for Index Scan but doing a filter on date after doing a scan on the resourceType.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216228/discussion-between-mahesh-v-s-and-laurenz-albe).

Comment: Yes. As I said in my answer, you have to change the query too: it must use the function rather than a cast. An index can only be used if one side of the operator is **exactly** the indexed expression.